# Session validation failed ZF3

Tags: php, ios, jwt, zend-framework3

In the mobile application, we are using API which is made using Zend Framework. Whenever a user tries to get the login to the app, they get authenticated using the JWT token.

But sometimes Zf3 gives exceptions as:

**Service with name \"Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService\" could not be created. Reason: Session validation failed...**

We have checked all the working scenarios but we failed to find the cause of the problem.

Below is the request header for the API:

```
{
    "Accept-Language" = "en;q=1";

    Authorization = "Bearer ***********ciOiJIUzU***RoX3Rva2VuIjoiMDh3d1hKSTc1MzAzOVh2NTV2eUx2dXBLIiwidXNlciI6MiwidG9rZW4iOiJhVGZsQmRp***R0dmSGlNbW80Q0d3OGJaNyIsImFwaV92ZXJzaW9uIjo*******H******5R5QPv09OjPcMoL3GlQ9IvcdU****7Q3sQHA";

    "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    Device = 1;

    Timezone = "+05:30";

    "User-Agent" = "****/*.0.2 (iPhone; iOS 10.3.1; Scale/2.00)"; (appname replaced with *)

    Version = 1;
}
```

Comment: NVM request, what did you write to validate session? Did you use example on this page? http://zendframework.github.io/zend-session/manager/